# how to get youtube playlist id from youtube video id?

Tags: javascript, api, video, youtube, playlist

is there any method to retrieve you tube playlist id.

what i need to retrieve the playlist id from you tube video id.

Please help me i have tried every thing but not found th solution if any one know please shre it.

Thansk

Comment: Take one of these http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]youtube+id